# Unable to correctly initialize xml-security library using ColdFusion 10.0

Tags: java, xml, coldfusion

I am using the following to initialize in CF 10 and I placed the xmlsec-1.5.8.jar file under Coldfusion10/cfusion/lib

```
<cfset Init = CreateObject("Java", "org.apache.xml.security.Init.Init()")>
```

I have also tried placing the above code in a cfscript as

```
Init = CreateObject("Java", "org.apache.xml.security.Init.Init()");
```

I am getting the following error.

You must initialize the xml-security library correctly before you use it. Call the static method "org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();" to do that before you use any functionality from that library.

Thank you.

Comment: Wrong syntax.  Create the object first, *then* call the method outside the function ie `createObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.Init").init()` .  That said .. this is a curious one.  I am not sure it will work since CF uses `init()` for a pseudo constructor.  It may end up creating a new instance, rather than invoking the static *method* named `init()`.

Comment: Ha, @Leigh we were typing much the same thing @ the same time it seems.

Comment: (Edit) @AdamCameron - Yep. I must have finished typing and went to eat just before the "new response" popped up. One thing though, I think the error message is referring to a method that is actually named init() - not the class constructor - or CF's pseudo-constructor init(). Not sure that is allowed from CF.

Comment: @Leigh: Oh yeah, good point. Didn't spot that. Will get rid of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the syntax error, there is another problem. The error message is indicating you must call a static method of that class first. One that is literally named [`init()`](https://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/Init.html#init%28%29). The problem is `init()` has a special meaning in CF. CF does not allow using the `new` keyword with java objects. Instead, it uses the name `init()` as a pseudo-constructor, which allows you to create a new instance of a class. So when you do this:

```
obj = createObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.Init").init();
```

CF will create a new instance of that class, NOT call a method named `init()`.  AFAIK, the only way around it is to use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). Something along these lines:

```
  // get a reference to the class
  ref = createObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.Init");
  // initialize if needed
  if (!ref.isInitialized()) {
      // find static method named "init" with no parameters
      method = ref.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("init", []);
      // invoke it via reflection
      method.invoke(ref, javacast("null", ""));
  }
```

> placed the xmlsec-1.5.8.jar file under Coldfusion10/cfusion/lib

While there is nothing wrong with doing that, as of CF10, you can also load jars dynamically via your Application settings, ie [this.javaSettings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html). If the feature seems familiar, it is basically a rip of [Mark Mandel's](http://www.compoundtheory.com/) [awesome JavaLoader.cfc](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/), only baked into CF ;-)