# Base64DecodingException: You must initialize the xml-security library correctly before you use it

Tags: java

Error while encrypting:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.exceptions.Base64DecodingException: You must initialize the xml-security library correctly before you use it. Call the static method "com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init.init();" to do that before you use any functionality from that library.
```

please help me i am getting this error in my encryption code, i use ibm integration tool, using java for encryption

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correctly initialize xml-security library using ColdFusion 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480784/unable-to-correctly-initialize-xml-security-library-using-coldfusion-10-0)

Comment: i am not that java expert,i know a bit of java only, please suggest what to do.

Comment: @VaibhavBharati Simply call the `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init.init()` method as requested?

Comment: hi tried that, but i am able to decrypt the string which i am encrypting, does that help u??

Comment: @VaibhavBharati try the solution suggested in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29482155/7643517